# Why does my stylesheet apply to one qtreewidget, but not another?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, stylesheet

I have two QTreeWidgets, and a stylesheet that is applied to both (via a common ancestor):

```
styleSheet += QString("QWidget:!active { ");
styleSheet += QString("  selection-background-color: %1; ").arg(inactiveHighlight.name());
styleSheet += QString("  selection-color: %1;            ").arg(inactiveHighlightText.name());
styleSheet += QString("}\n");
styleSheet += QString("QWidget:active { ");
styleSheet += QString("  selection-background-color: %1; ").arg(activeHighlight.name());
styleSheet += QString("  selection-color: %1;            ").arg(activeHighlightText.name());
styleSheet += QString("}\n");
```

The first tree applied the selection colors, the other does not.

I am using Qt 4.8.5 and have had this problem since Qt 4.6.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that one QTreeWidget has an edit delegate attached to it, the other does not.  This causes the drawing of the QTreeWidget's rows to be drawn by different objects.  One respects the 'old' CSS way, one follows the 'new' CSS way, as described in the link below.

[QStyledItemDelegate – Styling Item views](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2007/11/01/qstyleditemdelegate-styling-item-views/)

Thus the style also needs something similar to:

```
styleSheet += QString("QTreeView::item:selected:active { background-color: #123456; }");
```